# Remote ls on multiple machines

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I want to connect to multiple machines specified in a file and perform 'ls' there.

That's what I've come up with:

```
for machine in $(cat machines)
do
   echo "Connecting to " $machine
   ssh $machine ls -la && exit
done
```

Apart from the fact that I need to 'cd' to a different directory before the 'ls', the loop ends after the first entry in the file. This first entry is my machine itself, if that is important.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would guess that `exit` does shut your script down instead of your connection to the machine.
Just a guess, though, am no expert on this subject.

Comment: As other people have pointed out the `&& exit` doesn't need to be there. But if you want to have the `&&` happen on the target machine instead of locally, the easiest way is to quote it, eg `'&&'`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ssh $machine ls -la && exit
```

Your script `ssh`s to the remote machine which runs your `ls`.  `ssh` exits with success, `&&` sees this and runs the next command which is `exit`, so your script exits!

You don't need the `&& exit` at all.  When `ls` finishes, the connection will close and `ssh` will complete.  Just remove that bit and you'll be golden.

Answer (score 4):

You're not missing anything, you're *adding* something you shouldn't. The `exit` actually kills your session, it is not being run on the remote machine:

```
ssh foo@bar.com command && other_command
|---------------------|    |------------|
        |                        |----------> A completely separate command to be
        |                                     run if the ssh is successful 
        |-----------------------------------> The ssh command
```

Also, you don't need the `cd` (or the `cat`) at all, what you want to run is:

```
while read machine;
do
  echo "Connecting to " $machine
  ssh $machine ls -la /path/to/remote/directory
done < machines
```

Answer (score 3):

`exit` isn't run remotely but on this side (and is unnecessary). If you need to perform more than one command (like `cd`, `ls` and possibly more), just pipe a script to `ssh` and execute it remotely with `bash`. Something like

```
cat <<EOF | ssh "$machine" bash
  cd "$remote_dir"
  ls -la
  exit #if you actually needed this, it would be here, but you don't
EOF
```